# Using MobaXterm as Linux shell on Windows

Tags: python, windows, mobaxterm

I have a Python script which leverages `subprocess` to call MobaXterm and use it to run a command to my server through SSH. The script works fine when using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), but fails when using Moba. This is the code:

```
import subprocess

moba_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.exe"
subprocess.run(f'{moba_path} -exec ssh my_server "mkdir test_dir"')
```

It opens the MobaXterm window but does not show any sign of command execution. I checked, and the command has not been executed (the folder has not been created).

Any ideas?

Comment: try this because it's working for me 
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: That only uses the "ssh" installed in my Windows system. The thing is my ssh configuration is very convoluted and I would prefer to use Moba or WSL (some Linux system) since I already know the configurations there.

Answer (score 2):

So I found a way to execute my commands using Moba in a programmatic way using the `-newtab` command. It starts a new tab which then runs the specified command.

```
import subprocess

moba_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.exe"
subprocess.run(f'{moba_path} -newtab ssh my_server "mkdir test_dir"')
```